# Differentiation help

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am new in *Mathematica*. I want to differentiate

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = 
  Sqrt[(x + y) (1 - x - y) (x + z) (1 - x - z)] [x/((x + y) (x + z)) - y/ ((x + y) (1 - x - z)) - z/ ((1 - x - y) (x + z)) + (1 - x - y - z)/ ((1 - x - y) (1 - x - z))]
```

with respect to x, y and z. so I wrote the command

```
D[f[x, y, z], x] and  D[f[x, y, z], y] and  D[f[x, y, z], z].
```

Can anyone  please tell me is this correct?

Another thing is all the derivatives are giving same answer. Why? And what does pattern means in the answer ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Note that `sqrt` should be `Sqrt`.

Comment: No, your syntax is incorrect. The underscores in the derivative have to be removed, and the commas can't be used unless you surround the three expressions by `{` to make a list.

Comment: thanks a lot. I corrected the Sqrt . but i want three different derivates with respect to x,y and z. these are separate derivatives. D[f[x, y, z], x] and D[f[x, y, z], y] and D[f[x, y, z], z] are same . why ?

Comment: @Jens, i have corrected the question. Can you please tell me is it correct now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets in Mma are used only to specify function arguments.Your function is equivalent to the following (by using `FullSimplify[ ]`)

```
f[x_, y_, z_] :=  -((x (-1 + x + y) + (x + y) z)/
                   Sqrt[(-1 + x + y) (x + y) (-1 + x + z) (x + z)])
```

and then

```
{D[f[x, y, z], x] , D[f[x, y, z], y] , D[f[x, y, z], z]}
```

Comment: If in fact one wants the gradient: `D[f[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}]`

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I wasn't really sure ...

Comment: In any case `Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]` does the same

Answer (score 2):

Besides getting the syntax as discussed by belisarius, [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) will be very helpful to you in this case.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] :=
  Sqrt[(x + y) (1 - x - y) (x + z) (1 - x - z)] *
    (x/((x + y) (x + z)) - y/((x + y) (1 - x - z)) - z/((1 - x - y) (x + z)) + 
      (1 - x - y - z)/((1 - x - y) (1 - x - z)))

D[f[x, y, z], x] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> ((-1 + 2*x + y + z)*(y*z*(-2 + y + z) + x^2*(y + z) + x*(-1 + y + z)*(y + z))) /
>     (2*((-1 + x + y)*(x + y)*(-1 + x + z)*(x + z))^(3/2))
> ```

```
D[f[x, y, z], y] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> ((-1 + x + z)*(x + z)*((-x)*(-1 + x + y) + (x + y)*z)) /
>     (2*((-1 + x + y)*(x + y)*(-1 + x + z)*(x + z))^(3/2))
> ```

```
D[f[x, y, z], z] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> ((-1 + x + y)*(x + y)*(-x^2 + x*(1 + y - z) + y*z)) /
>     (2*((-1 + x + y)*(x + y)*(-1 + x + z)*(x + z))^(3/2))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using the corrected function:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Sqrt[(x + y) (1 - x - y) (x + z) (1 - x - z)] (x/((x + y) (x + z)) - 
    y/((x + y) (1 - x - z)) - 
    z/((1 - x - y) (x + z)) + (1 - x - y - 
       z)/((1 - x - y) (1 - x - z)))
```

to illustrate some other ways illustrating other forms or functions:

```
od = FullSimplify[
  Derivative[##][f][x, y, z] & @@@ {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
grad = FullSimplify[Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]]
totder = Collect[Dt[f[x, y, z]], {Dt[x], Dt[y], Dt[z]}];
td = FullSimplify[Coefficient[totder, {Dt[x], Dt[y], Dt[z]}]]
```

all yield:

> {((-1 + 2 x + y + z) (y z (-2 + y + z) + x^2 (y + z) + 
>       x (-1 + y + z) (y + z)))/(  2 ((-1 + x + y) (x + y) (-1 + x + z) (x + z))^(   3/2)), ((-1 + x + z) (x + z) (-x (-1 + x + y) + (x + y)
>   z))/(  2 ((-1 + x + y) (x + y) (-1 + x + z) (x + z))^(   3/2)), ((-1 +
>   x + y) (x + y) (-x^2 + x (1 + y - z) + y z))/(  2 ((-1 + x + y) (x +
>   y) (-1 + x + z) (x + z))^(3/2))}

`od` is just another to use `Derivative` function.

`grad` uses `Gradient` of scalar function

`Dt` provides total derivative and the other machinations just get the partial derivatives